# Javascript opens new window and loads _self

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

This code loads the href into a new window and into self, why is this?
Shouldn't return false; stop the default click?

```
//get links in paragraphs
var first_p = $$('#client_work p a');

//get first link
var client_link = first_p[0];

if(client_link) {
    $(client_link).observe('click', function() {

        var mylink = window.open(client_link.href, 'new_window', '_self');
        return false;   

    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
//get links in paragraphs
var first_p = $$('#client_work p a');

//get first link
var client_link = first_p[0];

if(client_link) {
    $(client_link).observe('click', function(event) {

        var mylink = window.open(client_link.href, 'new_window', '_self');
        Event.stop(event);   

    })
}
```

Comment: And so that was all I needed.
Thank you voD

Question: return false does not work here because Im in an event handler?

Comment: Prototype provides abstraction layer for event handling (therefore event propagation stopping). Read documentation http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event